# Make data available to all classes flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, iterable

I am making a `http get request` on my home page which returns a list of `Iterable`. I need to pass this result to a screen when a `tab` is clicked. It doesn't work well as expected as it returns null when navigating to the new sscreen. So am guessing thats not the right way to do it.

**HomePage**

```
class DashBoardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashBoardPageState createState() => _DashBoardPageState();
}

class _DashBoardPageState extends State<DashBoardPage> {
  List<MentorIndex> mentorIndexes = [];
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  Iterable newList;

  Widget callPage(int currentIndex) {
    switch (currentIndex) {
      case 0:
        showTabs = true;

        return TabBarView(
            //trying to pass this list to new tab screen
            children: [new HomePage(), new SchedulePage(), RequestsPage(menteeIds: newList,)]);
        break;

      default:
        return HomePage();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    fetchIndex();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '',


  }



 }
   Future fetchIndex() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var uri = NetworkUtils.host + AuthUtils.endPointIndex;
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
        uri,
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sharedPreferences.get("token"), },
      );
      final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      for (var u in responseJson["data"]) {
        MentorIndex user = MentorIndex(
            u["id"],
            u["mentor_id"],
            u["mentee_id"],
            u["status"],
            u["session_count"],
            u["current_job"],
            u["email"],
            u["phone_call"],
            u["video_call"],
            u["face_to_face"],
            u["created_at"],
            u["updated_at"]);

        mentorIndexes.add(user);
        newList = mentorIndexes.map((MentorIndex) => MentorIndex.mentee_id);
      }
      return responseJson;
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setState in your Stateful widget to change its state and rebuild the widget, right now you just pass the `null` value of `newList` which is assigned on creation.

In your `fetchIndex` method, wrap your `newList` assignment code with a `setState`, like so

```dart
        setState((){
           newList = mentorIndexes.map((MentorIndex) => MentorIndex.mentee_id);
        })
```

This way you will notify your `StatefulWidget` that its `State` object has changed and it needs to rebuild.